# Styling specific elements within a class

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to include condense this into one ".site-eval" declaration rather than having a .site-eval for each element?

````
.site-eval
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.site-eval a
{
    color:rgb(155, 85, 0);
}

.site-eval a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.site-eval li
{
padding-bottom: 10px; 
}```
````

Comment: Only in one of the css processors (such as sass, less, stylus) - where you simply nest `a` inside `.site-eval`, but not in raw css consumed directly by browsers

Answer (score 0):

**Using a CSS preprocesor like SASS (@Paulie_D's comment)**

```
.site-eval {

  a {

  }

  a:hover {

  }

  li {

  }
}
```

**Using plain CSS**

**(this syntax only applies if the selectors share styles, also not very maintainable)**

```
.site-eval a, .site-eval li {

}
```